# Sharepoint Content Query Web part selective subsite

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, content-query-web-part

Dear SharePoint Expert,

I want to create a Content Query web part in SharePoint 2013 called "Latest Upload":

```
 1. i created the web-part:
 2.in query  source: i selected --> Show items from the following site
 and all sub-sites: i chose a site.
 3.what i need to do is to exclude some of the folders or sub-sites that the query is retrieving data from.

**How can i accomplish that?**
```

Comment: You can try to filter by FileDirRef. This field contains url of the directory for an item. Try to output it in your content query web part and see if you can use it for filtering.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets i am using the edit web part (web version), when i attempt to add a filter there is a dropdown that i must choose from, there is no FileDirRef, how can i access it? or where do i find this filter. thx

Comment: "URL Path" column may be what you want.